# Feature request: put the time the page was rendered

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I log in SO/SU/SF, read just a few items/quetions and go to do some work (leaving the page open). Later on, I come back to read more items. Since the times are relative would be nice to have the base time they relate to printed somewhere in the page.

--
Versão em português:
Às vezes eu acesso SO/SF/SU, leio alguns itens (questões) e vou trabalhar ou fazer qualquer outra atividade (deixando a página aberta). Mais tarde eu volto e vou ler mais alguns itens. Uma vez que os horários sáo relativos, seria interessante ter o horário base a que eles se referem em algum lugar da página.

Comment: This could be done via Greasemonkey.

Comment: WTF? | En español: Que es el dealio?

Comment: No hablo espanol.

Comment: moon language!

Comment: Anne Heche and her damn space languages.

Comment: @Chacha: No hablo espanol. Falo português. And i try to speak english.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you refresh the page.

Even better: if you use Firefox, you could install the auto reload extension. Or you could have someone here write a Greasemonkey script for you to do what you want.

It just doesn't seem like much use to 99% of the community.

Comment: Just be very careful. I got banned because it went berserk on me.

Comment: I dont want to refresh. I want to read the remaining items on the page. But i´d like to know when they are effectively posted to the site.

Comment: So you want the times to update like clocks? To me this seems as ridiculous as the guy who criticized TheTXI for not adding real time updates to the vote count on a specific post. The obvious solution is to refresh the page, stop being stubborn.

Comment: @Ian Elliott: No, i dont want a clock. I want a base time.